# How can I access app data from a browser addon?

Tags: google-drive-api, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to add Google Drive integration to a browser add-on I developed. Basically I want to share user settings between devices, and the settings files are too big to fit inside the 100KB limit for the [storage.sync](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/sync) API.

But when I go to my API console and try and activate permissions for the Drive API, I get this:

[image]

Browser apps (and Android apps) aren't allowed to access app data. That's not just a warning, you actually can't continue the process until you choose a different platform. Weirdly, I can go ahead if I select "User data" (so user data is less sensitive than app data??)

What I like about app data over user data is that, if I understand correctly, app data goes in a hidden folder uniquely tied to your app, whereas user data goes in the actual user's drive. I don't want my app to have access to the broader drive, I don't want to risk messing their data up and I don't want them to see my app's config files every time they access their drive.

How can I get this "hidden folder" behavior from a browser addon?

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution from this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948410/google-drive-api-application-data-accessing-credentials-from-web-browserjavascr).

To be able to use your Application Data folder, request access to the following scope:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata
```